# Custom UITableViewEditingStyle w/ Checkmarks - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to duplicate the functionality found in the Settings app when managing the Spotlight search options:

[image: Pic1]

I need to be able to rearrange the order of a tableview without an editButton and will need to be able to select/deselect a cell, having the checkmark appear to the left of the cell label.

When I use the following code:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    return 3;
}
```

I get this:

[image: Pic2]

This works, but I was wondering if there was any way I could customize the editing style so that the checkmarks are more like they are in the spotlight settings (The red checkmarks look like items are being selected for deletion).

Possible duplicate of: [How can i custom UITableViewCell editing style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530238/how-can-i-custom-uitableviewcell-editing-style), but no one seems to have answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the editing style to `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`. Instead, create a checkmark image and a "blank" image (the same size at the checkmark image) and use these to set the cell's `imageView.image` property. You will need to keep track of which cells are checked or not. Toggle this state and the image view from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I used imageView.image to add the Checkmark image to each cell and I set shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath to return NO (so it doesn't indent). I just need to add the toggle functionality, but that shouldn't be too difficult.